# open() can't find file given path relative to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, ubuntu, path

I did `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/User/folder/test`. Then I ran python when I was in `/home/User/` and checked `sys.path` - it was correct.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gitosis-0.2-py2.7.egg', 
'/home/User', '/home/User/folder/test','/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Then I tried to open a file `/home/User/folder/test/pics/text/text.txt` like this:

```
>>>file = open('pics/text/text.txt','r')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

As you can see, first half of path to file is in `$PYTHONPATH`, and second half is given as an argument to `open()` function. Why doesn't it work? What should I change?

When I ran python from `/home/User/folder/test` (exported path) and tried to open file - it worked.

Comment: This is not what PYTHONPATH does; it only affects `import` statements.

Comment: So how I can open file without full file path?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open is relative to the current directory and does not use PYTHONPATH. The current directory defaults to whatever it was when python was started on the command line.

You can change the current directory with [os.chdir](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want your data to reside in a location relative to the module.  If that's the case, you can use:

```
full_path = os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[:-1]+['pics','text','text.txt'])
```

`__file__` is the path to the module (including `modulename.py`).  So I split that path, pull off `modulename.py` (`[:-1]`) and add the rest of the relative path via `os.path.join`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I want to import a script, relative to current and don't use packages, I usually use

```
sys.path = [os.path.dirname(__file__) + "/../another_dir"] + sys.path
```

Comment: I would use `os.curdir` and `os.pardir` in place of `'.'` and `'..'` and `os.path.join` instead of the `/`.

Comment: Why not just `sys.path.append`?

Comment: mgilson: sorry, just +"/../"; No, not the same: what you usually need is to import file from location, relative to script location, not the directory, you run the script from. Thus os.path.dirname(__file__) gives you the directory, where script is located, os.curdir gives you the directory, you run it from :)      

dinas: not sys.path.append to make sure, that python looks for the module in my location first, and next in all the other (cause if some lib contains a module with same name, or its older version is installed system-wide, you'll shoot yourself in the foot painfully) :)