# Python 2.7, Ubuntu 14.04: directory to load data from on sys.path, but file still not found

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu

Ok, this is a little bit of a strange one. I had some Python code that needed to load data from another folder using scipy's loadmat (this bit is not really relevant, but explains the remainder of the code). Before, I added the path at the beginning of the file via

```
path_to_add = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../data/unit_tests'))
if not path_to_add in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(1, path_to_add)
```

and would load the file via

```
mat_file = loadmat('test_kernel',squeeze_me=False)
```

This code ran fine in Ubuntu 12.04. However, when I try running it in 14.04, it gives the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_kernel.mat'
```

I printed out sys.path using 
    print sys.path
and sure enough, the right absolute directory with '/data/unit_tests' is present. If I go over to this folder and try to load the file using loadmat, it loads fine. But for whatever reason, even though the path is present on sys.path, I still get that error when I execute the script in another folder. Anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of scipy were you using and what version are you using now? You can check by running:

```
import scipy
print scipy.__version__
```

As far as I can tell in my version of scipy (0.14.0) it doesn't use the sys.path at all to find files when running `loadmat`. I've checked the source code and it looks like it simply passes in the filename to the builtin `open` function. Is there a chance on the Ubuntu 12.04 system you were running the script from the same directory as the mat file? As a sanity check try running the `loadmat` function with the full path to the mat file.

**Edit**

Here's a question with the same general problem: [open() can't find file given path relative to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391709/open-cant-find-file-given-path-relative-to-pythonpath)

The usual way to do what you are doing is either have a global "data" directory so when you need to load a data file you prefix the filename with that directory. Another way is to specify things as absolute/relative paths to the python script. If you get a little fancier and create a python package there are ways to load data files relative to the python package itself.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's a scipy problem; mine is version 0.13.3. If I pass in the full path, the load works. I just don't understand why after adding the path on sys.path, I have to reuse it again in the load. At that point, the file should have 'local scope', even though it resides in a different directory.

Comment: Python uses `sys.path` for finding python files/modules and it only does this when importing modules. I'm pretty sure matlab works in a similar way with `MATLABPATH`. `sys.path` has no effect on anything other than loading python modules (correct me if I'm wrong).