# Accessing textfile in parent directory failed in Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ubuntu

I put a text file outside the folder that contains python file, i.e.

```
a.txt
folder
  myPython.py
```

Following is the code I use

```
for line in open('../a.txt','rb'):
    print line
```

I works well in windows, but say

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../a.txt'
```

in Ubuntu 12.10, is there any problem on the specification of the path?

**Update**
It works when I use

```
fn = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../a.txt')
for line in open(fn,'rb'):
        print line
```

I am curious why this is possible..

Comment: are you sure there is file? its working on ubuntu for me.

Comment: It worked also for me.

Comment: @ChillarAnand thanks, i update the question for a working scenario..I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with Python 2.7, are you?

Comment: @badc0re thanks, I update the question, and I am using Ubuntu 12.10 with Python 2.7, are you?

Comment: But this way `'../../a.txt'` you are going two folders up, from the current location?

Comment: Are you running Python the `folder`? If you do `python /home/user/folder/myPython.py` with your cwd to `/var/somedir/` then `../a.txt` will refer to `/var/a.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figure it out from this question: [open() can't find file given path relative to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391709/open-cant-find-file-given-path-relative-to-pythonpath)

""Open is relative to the current directory... The current directory defaults to **whatever it was when python was started on the command line**""

When I change directory (cd) to folder level, it works for

```
for line in open('../a.txt','rb'):
    print line
```

Comment: This is not Python-specific, this is how pretty much all programs work... You can get the directory in which the script lives from `sys.argv[0]`